# Is using a string instead of a list to store multiple values going to work?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm using sqlalchemy currently but I can't store multiple values in a column. The only values I can put in a db are strings, int, etc. but not lists. I was thinking what if I wanted a list of integers and I just made it a string in this format: "1|10|91" and then split it afterwards. Would that work or would I run out of memory or something?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: It should work but I would recommend adding another columns. Isn't that possible?

Comment: It will probably work, but: (1) wanting to store lists in columns may be a sign that you actual want each list element to be a row in a child table with a foreign key linking it to the row in the parent table (2) the database may have column types that support this requirement already, such as array or json.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, in case you take care of the length of the column string in the database. So, for this case, it's better to use `Text` type column which has extended size in most of the database servers.

```
class model_name(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    integer_values = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can convert a **dictionary** easy to a **JSON file**. A dictionary consists of a bunch of variables. You can then convert the **JSON file** easy to **SQL**.

JSON files are often used to convert variables from one programming language to another.